# Where does Dashlane store the password vault on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer, password-management, dashlane

Can I choose where on my computer the Dashlane password vault is stored/located? And, were is it stored by default.

The answer sent back has nothing to do with my question.  They tell me to reinstall Dashlane etc..  I asked again and expect they will tell me to check if my laptop is powered up.

Anyone know?

Comment: Do you mean [dashlane](https://www.dashlane.com/)?

Comment: Are you using the Win32 Desktop application or the UWP application?  What version of Windows are you using?  What was their original response exactly?  If there is no option within the Dashline user interface, then it is unlikely, there is a way to store the files in a location of your choice.  Update your question and include this information.